# Error when trying to use hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, log4j

The error I'm receiving is listed [here](http://pastebin.com/5zeMxncH).

That's my HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.rosejapan;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new  AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch(Throwable e)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial sessionFactory creation failed.  " + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Everything looks all right... I've already included **log4j-boot.jar** in the CLASSPATH, but didn't resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that, using only annotations.

The following jars was used:

[image]

**With the code:**

Users.java

```
package firsthibernateapp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7960806792183842504L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String  myName;

    public Users()
    {

    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMyName()
    {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName)
    {
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        final Users other = (Users) obj;
        if (this.id != other.id && (this.id == null || !this.id.equals(obj)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
package firsthibernateapp;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_hibernate")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "root")
                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "100")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "10")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "0")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "100")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Users.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        // Get the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier
        // and prints out its member (myName)

        Users user = (Users) session.get(Users.class, 1);
        System.out.println("The user is " + user.getMyName() + "\n");

        // commit the changes, and close

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

I hope this can be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` clearly indicates an incompatibility problem with the version of Log4J you are using (a constructor expected to be there is not) and this is not surprising because (and I don't mean to be rude here) your whole dependency management (illustrated by the screenshot) seems to be a **BIG** mess:

- You have many unversioned libraries so it's impossible to know what you're using (in what version).
- You seem to be mixing things from various origins (at least two).
- You have several version of the same lib (e.g. cglib).
- You are mixing different versions of slf4j artifacts which [**can be problematic and is strongly discouraged**](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#compatibility).

So, since you're obviously not using any dependency management solution, my advice would be to use the JARs **provided with the Hibernate distribution** (put them in a clean directory) or at least to align the slf4j artifacts (e.g. on version 1.5.10 i.e. the version used by hibernate annotations 3.4) and to use log4j-1.2.14.jar. Your current workaround is a temporary fix hiding the real problem.